# WCF - Web Service Unsecured or Incorrectly Secured Fault

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, service-reference

I am trying to use a secure third party web service (which I have no control over) in my VB.Net app, and am getting the following error when trying to call the service:

> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.

Inner Exception:

> {"MustUnderstand headers: [{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security] are not understood."}

The service is secured via a user/pass and certificate. I created the WCF service reference via the wsdl just fine, and below is the code that I am using to set up the service. I have little experience  with web services, and I am out of ideas of what to try. Also, I am using .NET 3.5 if that helps anything. The code throws the exception on the line;

```
nameList.AddRange(service.getBlobNameByIdAndSectionId(section, id))
```

Full Code:

```
Private Function GetVendorService() As Services.ServiceClient
    Dim binding As New BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential)

    binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic
    Dim ea As New EndpointAddress(GetVendorServiceURL())

    Dim service As New Services.ServiceClient(binding, ea)
    service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user"
    service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password"

    Return service

End Function

Public Function GetVendorServiceURL() As String
    Select Case Informix.HostType
        Case HostServerType.Stage
            Return "https://url-s.net:8443/cxf/Service/v1/ws"
        Case HostServerType.Dev
            Return "https://url-d.net:8443/cxf/Service/v1/ws"
        Case Else 'Live
            Return "https://url.net:8443/cxf/Service/v1/ws"
    End Select
End Function

Private Function GetPdfListById(ByVal Id As Integer, ByVal Section As SectionId) As List(Of Services.blobName)
    Dim service As Services.ServiceClient = GetVendorService()
    Dim nameList As New List(Of Services.blobName)
    service.Open()
    nameList.AddRange(service.getBlobNameByIdAndSectionId(section, id))
    service.Close()
    Return nameList
End Function
```

App.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceSoapBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="ServiceSoapBinding1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://url-d.menards.net:8443/cxf/Service/v1/ws"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoapBinding"
    contract="Services.Service"
    name="ServiceSoapPort" />
</client>
```

Comment: Give your question a meaningful title

Comment: Tomcat, how many other questions created on [so], ***today***, are also about "WCF - Web Service"?

Comment: WCF sets the MustUnderstand headers to true/1 by default. My hunch is that either the server doesn't understand your WCF headers, or you need to set the MustUnderstand headers to false/0. I'm not entirely sure how to do that WCF client side though, which is why this is a comment and not an answer.